# Permutation representations of finite abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

What is a good source to study from about permutation representations of finite abelian groups, specifically $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$? If reference for the specific topic is not available, I would like to study about permutation representations in general (hopefully from a combinatorial viewpoint).

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I would like to explore if there is a possible connection with partitions. But apart from that, I need to know about the topic in general.

Comment: If you want to explore a possible connection with partitions, then you might get more helpful answers if you give some hint about what kind of connection. As it stands, it's very unclear what kind of answer you're looking for, and I've voted to close. As Daniel explains in his answer, there's very little to the classification of permutation representations of a finite cyclic group, especially of prime order, and it's unclear what more you want.

Answer (score 3):

Permutation representations of finite cyclic groups are pretty simple.

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $d$, and $g$ is a generator of $G$, then a permutation representation in $S_n$ is determined by the image of $g$, which must be a permutation of order dividing $d$.  A permutation of order dividing $d$ is one whose cycle decomposition consists of cycles whose orders divide $d$.  And a permutation is determined up to conjugation by its cycle type.

So, for instance, the permutation representations of a cyclic group of order 6 in $S_5$ would be (up to isomorphism)

- $\mathbb{1}$
- $(\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot)$

When $d$ is prime, things are even simpler, because the cycles can only be of order $d$.  For instance, the permutation representations of a cyclic group of order 5 in $S_{20}$ are

- $\mathbb{1}$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)$
- $(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)(\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot)$

And the *irreducible* representations are yet simpler: they just correspond to a single $m$-cycle, where $m$ divides $d$.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, surely there must be more theory on this topic. I am not just looking at understanding permutation representations in finite groups but also at possible connections of it to other topics.

Comment: I don't know how much more theory there can be.  So far as I know permutation representations aren't studied as their own subject; they're subsumed into linear representations, which are the "correct" thing to look at.